Why does my human face sculpt look weird outside of front view?
I'm fairly new to 3d sculpting, so I'm having an issue creating the basic form of a human face. In front view (and even side view to an extent), the sculpt appears to be coming along nicely. As soon as I leave perspective and start orbiting the mesh, it just looks awful.
Can someone tell me if this is normal for the early stages of a sculpt? It just looks so much worse outside of front view. Do I need to add more of a curve to the side of the face? I can't put my finger on the issue, assuming there is one?





I think you can look at references and see for yourself. It's part of the learning process, you have to learn to see how things truly are, see proportions, how muscles and bones are woven, and apply to your sculpt.

I'm not looking for pure realism right now. I'm just trying to create the basic form. I'm wondering if the screenshots provided look unusual for an early sculpt? And if so, can you see a specific issue with the form?

What focial length do you use in the viewport? The default is 50mm and it adds a lot of perspective to the model, especially if you zoom in. Try 85mm or even 100mm for portraits. The orthographic views of screenshot 1 & 2 have no perspective at all. Furthermore, the model has no ears, no eyebrows, unfinished eyes, nose and lips. This makes it look like an alien/snake. That's normal. In the screenshot 1, the drawn ears are added to the face and he looks more like a male human.

You can search for free basic human male models and compare with your sculpt, to better understand where the main issues are. I also found interesting to sculpt with an underlying mesh of a skull. I think that mainly it lacks a better definition of the orbits, wrong position of cheeck bones(too much prominent and too much close to the nose), wrong jaw line, wrong neck muscles, lack of Y deepness of the labial arc, ...
